# iOS 7: Blank Screen when presenting MFMailComposeViewController on navigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've got an app built using a storyboard, with a `navigationController`, and so far the only problem I'm having that I can't overcome is presenting a screen to send an email with a CSV attachment.

As far as I looked around, everything should be fine, and the app doesn't crash, it simply presents me a white screen when it should be showing me the mail composer view controller.

In my `ListViewController.h` (which is not the main controller, but a `MainViewController.h` is), I've got:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

...

- (IBAction) exportCSVToEmail;
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

In my `ListViewController.m`, I've got:

```
@implementation ListViewController

...

// Export CSV to email and send it
- (IBAction) exportCSVToEmail
{
    ...

    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposeViewController setSubject:emailSubject];
        [mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [mailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:textFileContentsData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:csvFileName];
        [mailComposeViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:^{
            //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
            NSLog(@"Completed showing the mail view!");
        }];
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

#pragma mark MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Finished sending email!");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

...
```

I'm trying this on my device (I've got mail accounts set).

The problem does not appear to be in the attachment or anything like that (I've tried commenting things out, using a simplified version, and the problem was the same).

It looks like I'm either not presenting the view controller in the right place, or I'm missing something in the storyboard?

I do see the `"Completed showing the mail view!"` in the console, and no error at all, just a blank, white screen (with the status bar black, and I can customize it with the commented line).

This is intended to work on iOS7 only, btw.

Help? :/

**UPDATE:**

After some more attempts and suggestions from other users, it seems that no matter what viewController I put in that `presentViewController:animated:completion`, it always shows up a blank screen. The fact it's "blank" is related to the gradient I've got on the window's main layer, defined in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    // Add background gradient
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.window.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.878431373 green:0.878431373 blue:0.878431373 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    [self.window.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    ...
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's some settings on my storyboard... maybe I'm not seeing something...

[image: storyboard screenshot #1]
[image: storyboard screenshot #2]

**UPDATE 3:**

I've experimented with a simple app with a navigation controller and 1 view that launches email and that works without a problem. I'm trying to find out what it is in my app that's not allowing that to happen the same...

Comment: You shouldn't need anything in the storyboard for this to work, other than that the controller this code is in is embedded in a navigation controller. I copied and pasted your code (commenting out the addAttachmentData: method and supplying text for the subject and body), and it worked for me on either the simulator or device (iPhone 4). You are definitely presenting something though (but blank)?

Comment: This controller is in the navigationcontroller with a push segue.

Also, even if I just use `[self presentViewController: ...` instead of `[self.navigationController presentViewController: ...` the behavior is the exact same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the problem, thanks so much for your help @Vibin and @rdelmar!

The problem was in my AppDelegate.m, where I had:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.window.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.878431373 green:0.878431373 blue:0.878431373 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
[self.window.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

It seems one can't do anything to the window for a storyboard application?

Anyway, now I'm out to probably add that gradient to each view controller instead of having it in the window :)

Thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with rdelmar. I tried creating a sample app having a blank controller embedded in the navigation controller using storyboard. Mapped my controller class to the storyboard view controller and copy pasted your code in viewDidLoad of my controller class. I did not comment any of your line. I was able to see the Email screen, with all details populated, on the simulator.

For debugging purpose, can you try out one of the following :

(1). Try setting your email screen as the first screen(root view controller) for navigation controller in storyboard and load it.

(2). Pull out the code from ListViewController and move it to a seperate UIViewController class that just implements the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate and its functions. Map your email controller class to this new class and then try loading it.

Please share your observations.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with (1) (I don't have a controller for the email screen, I create it programmatically in the `ListViewController`).

As for (2), while trying to do it, I realized that no matter the view controller I put in that code, it always loads a blank screen, which tells me the problem is definitely not with the MFMailComposeViewController class, but something else. Ideas?

Comment: Something ridiculous like `[self.navigationController pushViewController:mailComposeViewController.topViewController animated:YES];` shows the mail compose window, but the buttons don't work, for obvious reasons (the navigationcontroller is not there).

Comment: Hi Bruno, 
  Sorry for that. I think I was not clear in (1). What i actually meant was to try making the ListViewController as the root viewController of NavigationController and then try loading. This could have removed the possibility that the problem was not being caused due to some previously loaded view. Also one question is your current rootviewController's view getting loaded properly i.e without showing a blank screen?

Comment: It's mostly the fact that I'm new to iOS development.

Anyway, I've tried (1) and the problem was still the same (launching any view from anywhere with `presentViewController` is just loading up something blank). Should I have something on appDelegate? I'll try a new, simple application with just the MFMailComposeViewController and if that works, will compare both.

As for my rootViewController, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I see my MainViewController (the second screen, the tall one, in the storyboard) when I load the app, no blank screen before.

Comment: Hi Bruno,
 The first controller that the NavigationController points to is the rootViewController. In this case its the long controller that can be seen in the image. In storyboard, a rootviewController is represented by an arrow having a circle and two dots in between. Please let me know if you need help in making the ListViewController the rootviewController using storyboard.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I did and the result was the same like I reported above.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Good to have figured out the issue. I too was suspecting the same. Thanks for sending the update and the solution...

Comment: Hi Bruno,
 Just a quick question, how were you able to load the  MainViewController without being blank, as your code in appdelegate should have affected MainViewController also?

Comment: I did nothing special, just had the MainViewController with a clear background, which showed the gradient, and as the rootViewController for the navigationController. It worked.